# PHP - Desencriptar

Tags: php, encriptación

La encriptacion se realiza correctamente pero al momento de usar `openssl_get_privatekey` y guardarlo en `$key_resource` el valor queda en blanco por lo que arroja el error: `openssl_private_decrypt(): key parameter is not a valid private key in ...`

```
function encriptarDatos($datos){
        $fp=fopen("public.key","r"); 
        $pub_key=fread($fp,8192); 
        fclose($fp); 
        $key_resource = openssl_get_publickey($pub_key); 

        openssl_public_encrypt($datos,$encriptado,$key_resource ); 
        /*uses the already existing key resource*/ 
        return(base64_encode($encriptado));
    }

function desencriptarDatos($datos){
        $fp=fopen("private.key","r"); 
        $priv_key=fread($fp,8192); 
        fclose($fp); 
        echo "priv_key: $priv_key <br/><br/>";
        $key_resource = openssl_get_privatekey($priv_key);
        echo "key_resourse: $key_resource";

        openssl_private_decrypt($datos,$desencriptado,$key_resource); 
        /*uses the already existing key resource*/ 
        return(base64_encode($desencriptado));
    }
```

Luego lo coloque asi:

```
$fp=fopen("private.key","r"); 
            $priv_key=fread($fp,8192); 
            fclose($fp); 

            openssl_private_decrypt($datos, $desencriptado, openssl_pkey_get_private($priv_key, "phrase"));
            /*uses the already existing key resource*/ 
            return(base64_encode($desencriptado));
```

Pero el resultado esta en blanco tambien...

Comment: Según la documentación (http://php.net/manual/es/function.openssl-pkey-get-private.php),  a la función tienes que pasarle la contraseña usada al generar la clave para que pueda desencriptarla. Sólo si se ha generado sin contraseña no hay que pasarle nada.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta hacerlo así:

- Genera una `clave privada RSA`:

  ```
  > openssl genrsa -out private.pem 1024
  ```
- Extrae la `clave pública`:

  ```
  > openssl rsa -in private.pem -pubout -out public.pem
  ```
- Código `PHP`:

  ```
  <?php
  function encriptarDatos($texto)
  {
      $pub_key = openssl_pkey_get_public(file_get_contents('public.pem'));

      openssl_public_encrypt($texto, $encriptado, $pub_key, OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);
      return base64_encode($encriptado);
  }

  function desencriptarDatos($texto)
  {
      $priv_key = openssl_pkey_get_private(file_get_contents('private.pem'));
      $texto = base64_decode($texto);
      openssl_private_decrypt($texto, $desencriptado, $priv_key, OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);
      return $desencriptado;
  }

  var_dump($encriptado = encriptarDatos('Hola mundo!'));
  var_dump(desencriptarDatos($encriptado));
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Sin apenas saber de PHP, casi seguro que es un problema de permisos del archivo `privake.key`. Como su propio nombre indica, es la clave privada, que seguramente se ha generado con permisos de solo lectura para su dueño, y tu script PHP corre bajo el servidor o bajo fastcgi (fpm), por lo que su usuario será, seguramente, *www-data*, y no tendrá permisos de lectura sobre ese archivo.

Comment: Puedo leer el archivo, cuando coloco 'echo "priv_key: $priv_key <br/><br/>";' me muestra la private key, pero cuando uso '$key_resource = openssl_get_privatekey($priv_key);' es donde esta el problema porque '$key_resource' esta vacio